# Mongodb database model for password manager app

Tags: databases

I'm doing a school project where I have to design a password manager app. I was wondering what the data model would look like. I know that I will have the user database to store authentication informations but where do I put the informations when user create vaults? Would it be something like this?

User

{
username,
password,
name,
vaults:[]
}

If not can someone recommend me the correct data model for this?

Comment: Implementation questions are off-topic here.  I doubt anyone can tell you what is a "correct" data model, as it'll likely depend on the details of your app to a level that's beyond what can be provided here.  Also you haven't defined what "vault" means or what you mean by "where" you put the information.  I encourage you to try to build your app and see if that scheme works and if not, make whatever adjustments are necessary.

Comment: You might learn the most if you first try your best and write the implementation so that it works, and then ask about the design on Code Review SE. But there is no "correct data model".